# change the text box values according to the combo box selection

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am new in C# here i am trying to bind combo box with access database.
I bound the combo box with column name but i can not display the value of details(Column) in text box based on the selection of combo box.

in my database there is a table which contain the 3 coloumn
1.id
2.wesitename
3.Details
and 
this is my code

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\nazarmak\\Documents\\newwebsite.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select websitename, Details from newweb", con);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

         DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);


            this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "websitename";
            this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "websitename";
            this.comboBox1.DataSource = dt;



        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);


        }
        finally
        {

            con.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What textBox? It seems like you want to implement the `SelectedIndexChanged` Event in which you'll get, well, the index of the selected item of the comboBox and can work with that. One example would be to determin the `details` and setting some `textBox.Text` to that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set

```
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Details";
```

then you can get `details` as `this.comboBox1.SelectedValue`

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can do something like this

```
private void MyCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
MyTextbox.text=dt.Rows[MyCombobox.SelectedValue]["details"].ToString();
}
```

I guess this is what you are looking for

Comment: I want the text box values from database based on the selection of combo box value.

Comment: You mean that when a user clicks a website in your combobox (Lets say its www.abc.com) then its corresponding details should be displayed in your textbox..is that what you want? If yes then the above mentioned code does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you might be storing tables as the items of ComboBox. In this case if you want to look into columns and contents of each column (row details) you can try this in your event handler:

```
    DataColumnCollection columns = dt.Columns;
    DataRowCollection rows = dt.Rows;

    foreach (DataColumn column in columns)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(column.ColumnName + ": ");

        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
        {
            //display the cell value
            textBox1.AppendText(row[column.ColumnName].ToString());
        }

        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

    }
```